# check array for matches in dictionary value and return key

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{0: array([1, 0]), 1: array([0, 1])}
```

and I also have an array looking like this:

```
[[1 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]]
```

I'd like to check my array for a match in the dictionary value, so that it returns the key in a list:

```
[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]
```

Comment: Values are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsMgFET3nmKWChIM3QV6kuBCiKWSxsiPCUjo2a0x0GbT1fyZ/@CFFJ@zv@XspjBThF@nkGAW@MAG3LGrrpyNITKJ962E0kKivY6qdC3ezBT8t56sxDcrdsl//9q1YFT1cQ0vyzeBDiMeM2GU2OA8hsZFOy28iOkw9zT0J2yFrqQ9MKNZIOcjJyNy/gA)

```
import numpy as np
# Input data
d = {0: np.array([1, 0]), 1: np.array([0, 1])}
a = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
# Solve task
rd = {tuple(v) : k for k, v in d.items()}
ra = [rd[tuple(e)] for e in a]
print(ra)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The (very) inefficient O(n) solution would be to loop through the dictionary each time and find the required key:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
  # check for value and add key
```

But what is more efficient would be to store the values in tuples `(0,1)` so that the tuples can directly be accessed by the dictionary efficiently in O(1) time.

```
d = {(1,0): 0, (0,1): 1}
arr = [(1,0), (0,1)]
answer = [d[i] for i in arr]
```

Of course, you still need to check if the tuple exists in the dictionary itself, but the above code snippet is just a simple implementation